# Merge poly.shp line.shp & point.shp to single TAB file

Tags: qgis, tab

I am trying to use QGIS to avoid using commercial tools like Alteryx or FME to merge spatial files together.  However i cant seem to find any way of just joining different files together when the geom types are not the same.

The expected output will have a single GEOMETRY field and a combination of all the fields from the input files (with lots of blanks obviously).  Equivalent to a SQL UNIONALL really.

Can this be done in QGIS?

Comment: afaik geopackages should be able to store different geometry types at once. QGIS 3.x is able to handle these.

Comment: You are correct they can.  But do you know any way to get multiple layers into a single file / table?

Comment: That is a simple merge. If you want to have different symbologies, try rulebased styles.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do the 'simple merge'? the QGIS merge function only accepts layers of a single geometry type

Comment: Can't, sorry, still running 2.18 at work.

Comment: QGIS is using internally layers so that points, lines, and polygons are separated. Use ogr2ogr for combining your layer. Use switch "-nlt geometry". "-update" and -append" are needed as well.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how that works and what that syntax may look like? Would the destination be the same TAB file you specify for the first one? Can I run ogr2ogr from inside QGIS or the model builder or is it CLI only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested that this works from a command line. First create MapInfo TAB file from a line shapefile

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo file" combine.tab lines.shp
```

Add polygons from a polygon shapefile to the now existing layer "combine"

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo file" -update -append combine.tab polygons.shp -nln combine
```

Add points from a point shapefile to the now existing layer "combine"

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo file" -update -append combine.tab points.shp -nln combine
```